# What Adobe CS5 program should be used to make A4 multi-page brochure?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign

I want to know what Adobe CS5 program to use to make A4 multi-page brochure?

I have the full master suite so I wanted to know what is best to use for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

InDesign is usually the best bet for anything multi-page, although I've used Illustrator for simple two-sided trifolds.